# Is the electron a "magnetic" particle?

Tags: quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

Can we consider magnetic moment an intrinsic property of the electron like its charge? Just as we say that electron is a charged particle,  can we say electron is a "magnetic" particle?

Comment: I would say it's a duplicate of the second question, but not the first. Even so, the answers were low scoring.